# SharePoint list form conditional formatting - mandatory fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, list-form, validation, json-formatting

I'm trying to customize a list form using JSON.

The thing is I need to hide some fields depending on a value in a choice field (this I managed and it works) but I need those fields to be mandatory when they show up.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

(If I set the field as mandatory in the field's options, the formula is removed by the system and the field shows up on the form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, currently this is not possible using JSON customizations.

If field is required, you cannot hide it conditionally using formula.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer. hmm ..ok :-(